# Optimizing counting occurences of a list of words in a given string (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, list-comprehension

I am creating a function that counts the occurrences of `searched_words` in a passed string. The result is a dictionary with the matching words as keys and their occurrences as values.

I have already created a function that accomplishes this but it is very poorly optimized.

```py
def get_words(string, searched_words):
    words = string.split()

    # O(nm) where n is length of words and m is length of searched_words
    found_words = [x for x in words if x in searched_words]

    # O(n^2) where n is length of found_words
    words_dict = {}
    for word in found_words:
        words_dict[word] = found_words.count(word)

    return words_dict


print(get_words('pizza pizza is very cool cool cool', ['cool', 'pizza']))
# Results in {'pizza': 2, 'cool': 3}
```

I have attempted to use the `Counter` functionality from Python's `collections` model but cannot seem to reproduce the desired output. It seems using the `set` datatype may also solve my optimization problem but I am unsure of how to count word occurrences while using sets.

Comment: What exactly did you try with `Counter`? What is `searched_words`? In any case, using the above, you could do `return Counter(found_words)`. That is linear, but overall your algorithm will still be `O(M*N)`. To solve that, convert `search_words` to a `set`. Then it will all be linear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in thinking that there is a good solution using the `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

string = 'pizza pizza is very cool cool cool'
search_words = ['cool', 'pizza']
word_counts = Counter(string.split())

# If you want to get a dict only containing the counts of words in search_words:
search_word_counts = {wrd: word_counts[wrd] for wrd in search_words}
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something like this I think my trouble was mainly in getting a dictionary form from the return of ```Counter()``` or ```word_counts``` in your code. Thanks.

Comment: @TomBrinner `Counter` objects *are dictionaries*. Note, this solution is still polynomial time, `O(M*N)`. It can be done in `O(max(M, N))` if you make a set out of `search_words`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create a list comprehension of counts and then produce a dictionary out of **zip**:

```
def get_words(string, searched_words):
    wordlist = string.split()
    wordfreq = [wordlist.count(p) for p in searched_words]
    return dict(list(zip(searched_words, wordfreq)))
```

That's shorter and takes away extra **for** loop and no need for extra imports, yet it takes applying **dict** to **list** to **zip**.